# How can I insert a new element to slice when the method is self defined?

Tags: go, slice

When I tried to add a new method to an aliased type, `append` method not works.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)
    type Strings []string

func (ss Strings) Add(s string) {
    ss = append(ss, s)
}

func main() {
    ss := make(Strings, 0)

    ss = append(ss, "haha", "h3h3")
    fmt.Println(ss) // got [haha h3h3]


    ss.Add("lala")
    fmt.Println(ss) // also got [haha h3h3], and why ?
}
```

Why doesn't "lala" get appended to `ss`?

Comment: In short, if `Add()` may modify the receiver, the receiver must be a pointer: `func (ss *Strings) Add(s string) { *ss = append(*ss, s) }`. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JZSewRx9al).

Comment: Thanks @icza , it works now.